# Android Emulator isn't starting on Qt creator in ubuntu

Tags: android, android-emulator, qt5, android-virtual-device, qt-quick

I am totally beginner. I am using QT 6 it's automatically setup The SDK by clicking setup SDK. But i dont know why AVD is not running. I also tried to run this on terminal but terminal giving segment fault (core dump) error. please help me ! what can i do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after 25 days i found the solution on youtube. Here's the solution.
This solution works in my case.

https://youtu.be/AINs6dTBc0U